# NSMutableURLRequest: Can't get body to add with PUT request

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, http, put, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to perform a PUT.  As a test, I execute a GET request on some JSON data and store this receivedData in a variable data that I have initialized elsewhere.  I am able to decode the original data and everything looks fine.  When I send it back I wipe out everything in the HTTP body of the URI I am PUTting to.

```
  data = receivedData:

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:putURI]] autorelease];
     [request setTimeoutInterval:10];
     [request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
     [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
     [request addValue:self.token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
     [request setHTTPBody:data];
     NSLog(@"\nVerify existence of original data packet: \n%@\n\n",data);

     self.putDeviceOnListConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Any ideas what is wrong?  Your help is greatly appreciated, as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem with this.  I have added a addValue:forHTTPHeaderField for for the length of the data packet and changed the content-type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Great stuff, I added the Content-Type and it worked.